# Electron Packager - working with relative paths

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I was wondering how I would deal with relative paths within my application when using electron packager.

In my app source folder I have some json files and other files that I reference. When packaging, electron-packager creates the \resources\app directory and places all these files into that directory. This means that any relative paths I'm using during development fail in the packaged app.

I tried pre-emtping this by creating the \resources\app folder in my source directory hoping the packager would notice them and just move them directly but it created \resources\app\resources\app instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had success using [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) along with [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath) to build paths to assets.

I like `upath` rather than `path` because it has a `toUnix` method which "replaces the windows \ with the unix / in all string params & results."

```
var imgPath = upath.toUnix(upath.join(__dirname, "assets","welcome.png"));
```

Comment: Do these change when packaging though? My issue isn't necessarily that i can't access the path - it's that the electron-packager creates folders and moves files so the relative paths break when packaging.

Comment: *"it's that the electron-packager creates folders and moves files so the relative paths break when packaging."* That's not been my experience. Maybe my directory structure is different.

Comment: maybe. For me, the main executable that is generated is in the apps root folder, then all resources that were previously in the root dir are put into the /resources/app folder.

Comment: Thanks, using __dirname was the part I was missing. That variable will always resolve to the correct directiory.